# Move file to another directory using sql query

Tags: mysql, sql, database, phpmyadmin

I have a file uploaded in:

`/var/lib/mysql-files/`

I want to move this file to:

`/home/user/public_html`

using sql query command only

I know it is possible with linux commands cd, mv
But in my case, I can do it only using sql commands.

Or, is there a way to change the `SELECT @@global.secure_file_priv;
Value /var/lib/mysql-files/` to `NULL` using sql commands ?

Comment: Sorry, Tag edited

Comment: *"Or, is there a way to change the SELECT @@global.secure_file_priv; Value /var/lib/mysql-files/ to NULL using sql commands ?"*  Trust me you do not want that...Setting that to NULL allows a attacker when there is a possible SQL injection to generate and place a backdoor (with a simple SELECT `<?php //php backback code ?> INTO OUTFILE|DUMPFILE '<web_server_path>/backdoor.php'`) in anny web application and execute it in a webserver.. **Because `secure_file_priv` is meant to protect against that don't change it to NULL**:

Comment: I am testing a vulnerability. I know somebody  can upload  files  if i change to null.